# Disable scroll for mobile browsers with css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, scroll

I am working on mobile application for web browser. I want to disable **vertical scroll** when popup(not browser alerts i.e. created popup using css) is open.

I am using css to disable **vertical scroll**

```
body{overflow:hidden;
}
```

so it will hide the scroll or we can say disable scroll, its working fine for web browser

http://www.enggheads.com/#!question/1420697656675  [Here is my website link](http://www.enggheads.com/#!question/1420697656675)

Comment: can you share some link with a demo (jsfiddle or link  to your app)

Comment: Have you added meta tag within head tag? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">

Comment: yes i have already added.
http://www.enggheads.com/#!question/1420697656675

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

-y is for vertical scrolling